# button.mouseHover change button background image slow

Tags: c#, background-image, mousehover

I have written some code to change a button's background image on mouse-hover, however when the image is changes it seems that it is a bit slow to complete.

That is, the process of setting the new picture as its background image is slow. By slow I mean a few milliseconds, but still enough to be seen!

Is there anything I can do about this, to speed up this process?

Comment: Can we see some code of what you have so far?

Comment: hey thnx for the response but never mind! just solved the problem i needed to use MouseMove instead of MouseHover!

Comment: Can you answer your own question in a way that would help others? If you do, you can select yours as the correct answer. It may seem strange, but it is preferred to deleting in situations like this.

Answer (score 2):

let use mouse move (the mouse overed control)